# How to adjust Image position in XYImageAnnotation

Tags: java, icons, jfreechart, bufferedimage

I have a icon in JFreeChart:

```
BufferedImage torreIcon = null;

try {
    torreIcon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(
        "Resources/Imagenes/torre_control_2.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I have added this icon to the `XYPlot`:

```
XYAnnotation xyannotation = new XYImageAnnotation(0, 1900, torreIcon);
this.xyplot.addAnnotation(xyannotation);
```

And the result in the chart is:

[image]

The problem is when I make zoom in:

[image]

I would like that the icon always be next to the x axis, without space, and with the same size of course. Is it possible?

Comment: Why is the _y_ coordinate 1900, if it should be 0?

Comment: If i put (0, 0) coordinates, the icon center is put in  0 , 0 and the image is not above x axis. I put manually the coordinates that makes the icon put above the x axis initially, and as we can see the y coordinate that make this is 1900.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I put (0, 0) coordinates, the icon center is put in 0, 0 and the image is not above *x* axis.

Correct; unless otherwise specified, an [`XYImageAnnotation`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYImageAnnotation.html) is *centered* at the specified data space coordinates using `RectangleAnchor.CENTER`.

> I put manually the coordinates that makes the icon put above the *x* axis initially, and as we can see the *y* coordinate that make this is 1900.

Instead, specify the desired `RectangleAnchor` when you construct the `XYImageAnnotation`:

```
new XYImageAnnotation(0, 0, image, RectangleAnchor.BOTTOM)
```

The example below adds a blue frame to a convenient image in order to see how the image is drawn relative to the anchor. `RectangleAnchor.BOTTOM` at the origin is illustrated below. The image stays anchored to the origin as you pan and zoom. Try the other `RectangleAnchor` instances to see the effect.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.annotations.XYImageAnnotation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.RectangleAnchor;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/71780485/230513
 */
public class XYImageTest {

    private static final int N = 1;

    private XYDataset createDataset() {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Series");
        for (int i = -N; i <= N; i++) {
            series.add(i, i);
        }
        return new XYSeriesCollection(series);
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset, Image image) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Test", "X", "Y", dataset);
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setDomainPannable(true);
        plot.setRangePannable(true);
        plot.addAnnotation(new XYImageAnnotation(0, 0, image, RectangleAnchor.BOTTOM));
        return chart;
    }

    private void display() {
        Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),
            icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, image.getWidth() - 1, image.getHeight() - 1);
        icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
        g.dispose();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("XYImageTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(createChart(createDataset(), image)) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 300);
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new XYImageTest()::display);
    }
}
```